# Can I combine 2 queries into one data array from 2 different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a media library that lets a user organize files into folders.  I have a table for files that tracks the parent id of the folder it belongs to.  I also have a folders table that also allows for a parent id - so a folder can be in another folder.  The problem becomes when I want to show a view that lists both the files and folders that a parent folder contains. Up until this point I have taken the cheap way out and have just done 2 separate queries for the folders, then the files - and then just listed one right after the other. However, now that the lists have gotten long - I want to paginate them - so I need to LIMIT my query.  How can I combine 2 queries to get one data array of files and folders I can loop through?

For example, I can do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `files` LEFT JOIN `folders` ON `files`.`folder_id` = `folders`.`id` 
WHERE `folders`.`id` = 198
```

That will give me a list of all the files in that folder.

Then this:

```
SELECT * FROM `folders` WHERE `parent` = 198
```

That will give me a list of all the child folders.

Is there a way I can combine the two to give me a single data array to loop through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT id_file, name, 'file' as `type` 
FROM `files` 
LEFT JOIN `folders` ON `files`.`folder_id` = `folders`.`id` 
WHERE `folders`.`id` = 198

UNION

SELECT id_folder, name, 'folder' FROM `folders` WHERE `parent` = 198

LIMIT 0, 20
```

Comment: He only needs to set the field aliases in the first query. The other query after `union`, will use the same fields with their aliases.